# Can (Chrome's) HTML5 canvas display Adobe Typekit fonts?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, fonts, typekit

I have a canvas that will display Verdana correctly, as long as I don't specify bold (in which case it defaults to Times. I would like to use Typekit fonts on the canvas, but it doesn't seem to be registering: I have weights of 400 and 700 loaded, e.g. by 'normal 12px "proxima-nova"', but so far it seems to always default to Times.

How can I get an HTML5 canvas, at least in Chrome, to correctly display Typekit fonts? I want normal and bold weight to be available; do I need weights of 500 and 900, or should it be doing something on 400 and 700?

TIA,

Comment: Never mind; as stated in the legalese, it can take a few minutes for a font to be available, and my attempt to load the font was getting a 404 because the font had not yet propagated.